What does debye length mean in the context of an electron beam?
I was reading a paper on cathode rays and I came across a section that discuss debye length in terms of electron beam.
Here's the paper
http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/10MIT/Lecture2_Emission_and_Cathode_Emittance_slides.pdf
the section on debye length is on page 19
Here's the relevant quote

The internal forces results from the mutual interactions between
the electrons, which can be classified into collisions and smoothly varying forces.
The collisional forces occur between nearest neighbors and are random, statistical
fluctuations related to the beam temperature. On a larger scale lengths the elec-
trons will collectively move to screen any non-uniform of the electron distribution,
resulting in a slowly, varying spatial field. This screening of the single-particle
forces is called Debye shielding [Reiser, p 184; Jackson, 1st Edition, pp 339] and is
effective for distances greater than the Debye length, λD

From what I understand Debye length is used in plasmas and electrolytes where it describes  the distance beyond which the electric field of the charge falls off due to screening by opposite charges.
What I don't understand is where do these opposite charges come from in an electron beam that is operated in a hard vacuum. What does the debye length in this case indicate?Here it seems to be talking about screening by simillar charges. How is this possible?
Thanks.

The following likely has a better explanation for Debye shielding (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019PhPl...26e0701L/abstract).  As an aside, there is no such thing as a "hard vacuum" or region of space with only electrons.  The plasmas that exist in space have both ions and electrons and Debye shielding occurs because electric fields do work to get rid of themselves (over simplification but that's the general idea).

@honeste_vivere Thank you so much for sharing that paper,I'm trying to understand it. But coming to your second point if I understand you correctly what you are saying is that in scenario in the question there would be some gas molecules left that would be ionized and lead to debye shielding in the electron beam.

No, it's generally simpler than that... The generation of a plasma involves liberating electrons from atoms, thus you will always have ions and electrons.  Does that help?

@honeste_vivere Thanks. It does help. Just to clarify what you are saying is that they are talking about the debye length in the generated plasma & not in the electron beam. Did I understand you correctly?

The Debye length makes no sense in isolation.  It only makes sense in a quasi-neutral plasma.
